# Windows popup interaction for downloading using selenium webdriver in python

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, firefox-profile

I am making a programme to automatically download the data using selenium webdriver in python. When i click on "download" button following popup occours

.[image]

with default option "Open with" selected. I want my program to first click on the option "save file" and then click on "OK". 
I have used following piece of code to set up Firefox profile

```
    profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
    profile.set_preference('browser.download.folderList', 2)
    profile.set_preference('browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting', False)
    profile.set_preference('browser.download.dir', os.getcwd())
    profile.set_preference('browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk', "application/xlsx")
```

But it is not working in my case. Then I tried to switch to this window from main window by using following code

```
    parent_h = driver.current_window_handle
    handles = driver.window_handles
    handles.remove(parent_h)
    driver.switch_to_window(handles.pop())
```

But now I am not getting how to interact with this window?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After so much findings and research, I get the following code which would be helpful for this type of situation.

```
    profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
    profile.set_preference("browser.download.dir",os.getcwd());
    profile.set_preference("browser.download.folderList",2);
    profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/csv,application/excel,application/vnd.msexcel,application/vnd.ms-excel,text/anytext,text/comma-separated-values,text/csv,application/vnd.ms-excel,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet,application/octet-stream");
    profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting",False);
    profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.openFile","application/csv,application/excel,application/vnd.msexcel,application/vnd.ms-excel,text/anytext,text/comma-separated-values,text/csv,application/vnd.ms-excel,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet,application/octet-stream");
    profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force", False);
    profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.useWindow", False);
    profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.focusWhenStarting", False);
    profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.alertOnEXEOpen", False);
    profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showAlertOnComplete", False);
    profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.closeWhenDone", True);
    profile.set_preference("pdfjs.disabled", True);
```

Comment: after trying various SO solutions, i tried `pdfjs.disabled` as you mention, and it worked. however for me it only works in conjunction with `browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk`, and the other settings are not needed.

Answer (score 3):

You should try to use preference with correct `MIME` type for `xlsx` extension which is `"application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"`, but not `"application/xlsx"`:

```
profile.set_preference('browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk', "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet")
```

You can check list of `MIME` types for Microsoft Office files [here](http://filext.com/faq/office_mime_types.php)

Comment: After using this mime also same pop-up window is appearing. Can you tell me another solution.